# $_SESSION is empty in php sub-scripts even after session_start()

Tags: php

I have a working authentication mechanism. In a login.php I load all the user data into the $_SESSION. When I access the data via var_dump($_SESSION); in the index.php, I get all the data I saved into the $_SESSION.

Now I want to access it in the nav.php, which is loaded when the user is authenticated (via checking the $_SESSION['loggedin'] conditional). But when I try to use the $_SESSION['loggedin'] field, I dont get any. The $_SESSION in nav.php is completely empty. Even after session_start(); How is that possible?

**index.php**

```
<?php
  session_name('mysession');
  session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 7200,
    'gc_maxlifetime' => 7200,
    'use_cookies' => 1,
    'use_only_cookies' => 1
  ]);

...

// Check authentication, get department from Ldap and make content visible if authenticated
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1) 
{
  $USERNAME = $_SESSION['USERNAME'];
  $ROLE = $_SESSION['ROLE'];
  $DEPARTMENT = $ldap->getOneAttrAd($USERNAME, 'department');

  $nav = file_get_contents("View/Nav/nav.php");
  $sidenav = file_get_contents...
  ...
} else { include "Service/resetSession.php"; }

<html lang="de">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Content is only visible if the user is authenticated --!>
    <nav id="nav" class="frame"><?php echo $nav ?></nav>
    <div id="sidenav" ...
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

**nav.php**

```
<?php
  session_name('mysession');
  session_start();
?>

<div class="nav-container">
  <h1 id="nav-title">My Navigation bar</h1>
  <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1)
    {
      echo ("<button id='logout-button' name='logout-button' class='sec-button' type='button'>Logout</button>");
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `file_get_contents()` to load your nav, `include()` the file. (`file_get_contents()` "_reads entire file into a string_", it doesn't run PHP code)

Comment: fyi, if your user is _not_ logged in `$nav` will most likely not be set, `echo $nav` should fail

Comment: @brombeer I changed it but still the $_SESSION is empty in nav.php. When I make a var_dump after the session_start(), the result is array(0){}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1) 
{
  ...
  $nav = file_get_contents("View/Nav/nav.php");
  ...
}
...
 echo $nav //what if user not logged, you'll get an error
```

I suggest

```
<?php
  session_name('mysession');
  session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 7200,
    'gc_maxlifetime' => 7200,
    'use_cookies' => 1,
    'use_only_cookies' => 1
  ]);

...

// Check authentication, get department from Ldap and make content visible if authenticated
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1) 
{
  $USERNAME = $_SESSION['USERNAME'];
  $ROLE = $_SESSION['ROLE'];
  $DEPARTMENT = $ldap->getOneAttrAd($USERNAME, 'department');
  ...
} else { include "Service/resetSession.php"; }
?>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Content is only visible if the user is authenticated --!>
    <nav id="nav" class="frame"><?php include("View/Nav/nav.php"); ?></nav>
    <div id="sidenav"> ... <?php //include (sidenav_location); ?></div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I tried it your way but still the $_SESSION in nav.php is an empty array. When I var_dump($_SESSSION) I get array(0){}

Comment: Here the code: (Like above but with a var_dump in it.

```<?php
  session_name('mysession');
  session_start();
  var_dump($_SESSION);
?>

<div class="nav-container">
  <h1 id="nav-title">My Navigation bar</h1>
  <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1)
    {
      echo ("<button id='logout-button' name='logout-button' class='sec-button' type='button'>Logout</button>");
    }
  ?>
</div>```

Comment: Your suggestion is correct. It was actually the include statement, that prevented it. Thank you!